# Cambiar formato de fecha recibida por API

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, date

Recibo una fecha que se coge por base de datos con el formato dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss. Intento transformalo a yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss, pero no lo consigo.he porbado diferentes formas pero no lo consigo.

He probado de esta forma:

```
              let prueba:Date = await this.getDataBD();              
              let date2 = this.datePipe.transform(prueba, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
              console.log(date2)
```

pero me da error **Unable to convert "13/03/2024 08:12:27" into a date' for pipe 'DatePipe**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que DatePipe espera un objeto Date como entrada. Primero debes pasar la cadena a un objeto Date:

```
let fechaStr = "13/03/2024 08:12:27";
let partes = fechaStr.split(/[\s/:-]/);
let fecha = new Date(+partes[2], partes[1]-1, +partes[0], +partes[3], +partes[4], +partes[5]);
```

Y luego ya puedes utilizar DatePipe:

```
let datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
let nuevoFormato = datePipe.transform(fecha, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
console.log(nuevoFormato);
```

Comment: Genial! me funciono! Entiendo que la pasaba un date pero no con el formato que necesita el datePipe?

Comment: @Brian parece más bien que es un string, has un `console.log` usando `typeof` para ver que es lo que trae.

Answer (score 1):

Dado que hablamos de pasar de un *formato* de fecha a otro *formato*, ambos representados en cadenas de texto, siento que es demasiado trabajo convertir a fecha, para luego pasar al otro formato, cuando podemos simplemente transformar la cadena moviendo sus partes, por ejemplo:

```js
let fechaStr = "13/03/2024 08:12:27";
let nuevoFormato = fechaStr.substring(6, 10) + '-' + fechaStr.substring(3, 5) + '-' + fechaStr.substring(0, 2) + ' ' + fechaStr.substring(11, 19);

console.log(nuevoFormato);
```

También puedes hacerlo con split, en caso que puedan variar las longitudes de día y mes:

```js
let fechaStr = "13/03/2024 08:12:27";
let partes = fechaStr.split(/[\s/:-]/);
let nuevoFormato = partes[2] + '-' + partes[1] + '-' + partes[0] + ' ' + partes[3] + ':' + partes[4] + ':' + partes[5];
console.log(nuevoFormato);
```